# Handling dups returned from a query

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have the below query that returns a few duplicates.

```
SELECT DISTINCT number, owner, date, provider FROM
data.provider
```

Output -

```
"05"    "Government - State/ County"    "1966-07-01"    "H"
"05"    "Proprietary"                   "1966-07-01"    "H"
"67"    "Proprietary"                   "2002-12-16"    "H"
```

I want the query to return only one record for duplicate `number` column records. So, I want this output instead -

```
"05"    "Government - State/ County"    "1966-07-01"    "H"
"67"    "Proprietary"                   "2002-12-16"    "H"
```

I want it to distinguish between the two "05" records based on the year of the record. The latest year wins. Year is part of the `provider` table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `row_number()`. To get the unique number for each provider.

```
select * from 
    (select row_number() over (partition by owner, number order by date) rn
        , number, owner, date, provider from data.provider) t1
where t1.rn = 1
```

Answer (score 2):

In Postgres, I would recommend `DISTINCT ON`:

```
SELECT DISTINCT ON (number) number, owner, date, provider
FROM data.provider
ORDER BY number, date DESC;
```